# How do I detect Facebook login status in PHP after Javascript logout?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, sdk, logout

I'm calling the FB.logout() and FB.login() functions in the Javascript SDK.

In each case, I'd like to call a PHP "sync" script via AJAX to keep my server status up-to-date. For example:

```
FB.init({
    appId:'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    cookie: true,
    status : true,
    xfbml:true
});

FB.logout(function(response) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://mysite.com/sync.php",
    cache: false
    ...
    });
}
```

Then in the sync.php script:

```
    $user = $this->api->getUser();

    if ($user) {
        try {
            $me = $this->api->api('/me');
        }
        catch (FacebookApiException $e){
            error_log($e);
            $user = false;
        }
    }

    if ($user)
        echo json_encode(array("status" => "logged in"), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    else
        echo json_encode(array("status" => "logged out"), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

So after calling FB.logout, why does sync.php always return status "logged in"?

I know I could call the Facebook PHP login or logout functions after calling Javascript FB.login() or FB.logout(), but do I really have to do that to keep both SDK's working together?

By the way, the sync.php script returns "logged in" whether I call it via AJAX immediately within FB.logout() or after a page refresh at a later time.

Thanks for any help.